# Java Reflection // Can not set java.lang.Boolean to (boolean)true

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class which has a field named "bool" of type *java.lang.Boolean* and try to set its value via reflection with the following code:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
try {
    Field field = myClass.getClass().getField("bool");
    field.setBoolean(myClass, true);
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I always get the following error: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Boolean field MyClass.bool to (boolean)true*

Passing an instance of *new Boolean* instead of *true*, *Boolean.TRUE*, or *new Boolean(true).booleanValue()* didn't work either.
Interestingly, it works flawlessly if I change the type of *java.lang.Boolean* to *boolean*. However, I need to be able to process java.lang.Boolean, too.

How can I set a java.lang.Boolean via reflection?

Comment: What is the definition of `myClass.bool`?

Comment: `field.set(myClass, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
field.set(myClass, Boolean.TRUE);
```

to set the field to an Boolean value.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Just forgot to remove the comment.

Answer (score 2):

`setBoolean` method will work only if `bool` variable was of a primitive type `boolean`.

Give that `bool` variable is of type `java.lang.Boolean` - as @shmosel suggested in the comments - you should simply use `set` method and the `true` value will be autoboxed into a `Boolean` .

```
field.set(myClass, true)
```